# Is there anyone directly write a paper in Tex Live processor?

Tags: texlive

I learn to use LaTeX for a couple of weeks, and i usually directly write contents in the Office Word processor and then copy them into the TeX Live processor. Is there anyone directly write a paper in TeX Live processor ? or do the same as what i did? (I hope you can understand my question because of my poor english.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm not sure I understand well. Do you mean you convert your Word document to LaTeX with some software, or you you simply copy-paste it as text in a .tex file?

Comment: @Bernard, hi, i mean i simply copy-paste it into the TeX Live.

Comment: What's the advantage w.r.t. directly typing in a dedicated editor?

Comment: It's only in English (sorry!) but I recommend you familiarize yourself with [the topics I discuss here](http://seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html). It will help you learn the terminology :)

Answer (score 4):

We use an "editor", which supports LaTeX, to write a text. Common editors are listed here: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/4736) and in wikipedia, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors .

About the concept of an editor, please read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor (This article may have been translated to your language!).